# How to set child nodes into parent nodes in XML?

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML document in this format:

```
<EX>
    <file filename="File1">
        <form name="form1"/>
        <form name="form2"/>
        <form name="form3"/>
    </file>
    <file filename="File2">
        <form name="form2"/>
        <form name="form3"/>
    </file>
</EX>
```

... which I need to convert to this format:

```
<EX>
    <form name = "form1">
        <file filename="File1"/>
    </form>
    <form name = "form2">
        <file filename="File1"/>
        <file filename="File2"/>
    </form>
    <form name = "form3">
        <file filename="File1"/>
        <file filename="File2"/>
    </form>
</EX>
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Please explain in which context you are trying to do this (PHP code, etc.). We need more info.

Comment: I already tried looping and creating new xml using c# as defined in answer below. I am new to programming, and i am trying to find out if there is easier way to do it.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Heres one way you could do it:

loop through your original xml doc and create a new one with a node for each child node in your original doc.  Then loop through your original document again, creating corresponding children in your new doc.

Comment: This is not exactly helpful (yet?). Consider adding code that shows what you mean.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I already tried something similar, your way is litte better. I was trying to find out if there is any solution other than looping. I have a large xml file, so was tying to find if there is something easier that i am missing.